# What gives additional scores in the game?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Some of wars you run give additional scores, you can see on the screenshot that Ottomans earned quite a few good quests:

- 2nd Makurian Purge of Funj Heresy:
- 3rd Georgian Reconquest of Mingerelia

I (play France) also had some of them, mainly related to expansion and colonization ideas.

But not all my wars give score.

**Question:** how to know what war will give you score?

Thanks.

P.S. I recently completed a couple of different quests (missions, colonization or exploration tasks) nothing gives the bonus anymore...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I have found the answer or at least a good guess.

In order to get scores from at least colonial conquest you should take defeated country into protectorate. This way you get scores :)

Neither annexation, nor getting money give you those scores. Only Protectorate.  See "French Conquest of Ojibwe" line.

[image: Score screen with points for making opponent protectorate]

Comment: Actually, I've gotten 'quest score' for getting money as well... so logic could be more complicated... Any additional information is still welcome!